# getElementsByClassName not working when I change to different class name

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, getelementsbyclassname

I've looked over numerous Stack Overflow discussions on `getElementsByClassName` but can't seem to find anything that can help me resolve this particular issue. To explain . . .

I have the following javascript

```
    field_to_update.innerHTML = '';

    var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
    elOptNew.text = '---'
    elOptNew.value = '';

    field_to_update.add(elOptNew);

    field_to_update.options[0].selected = true;

    var track_names = document.getElementsByClassName('wpaudio');   

    for (i=0; i<track_names.length; i++) {
    
        var track_name = track_names[i].innerHTML;

        var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
        elOptNew.text = track_name.replace("&amp;", "&");
        elOptNew.value = track_name;

        field_to_update.add(elOptNew); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE

    }
```

and I am looking to extract the names of a list of audio files using the line  `var track_names = document.getElementsByClassName('wpaudio')` which refers to the following code included in the functions.php file of a wordpress child theme.

```
<ol id="audioFilesList" class="reactionFormAudio">
            <?php 
            // loop through rows (parent repeater)
            while( have_rows('song_upload') ): the_row(); ?>
               
               <li><p class="wpaudio" name="audioFileName"><?php the_sub_field('track_name'); ?></p><br>
```

The above scenario works fine. BUT i have decided to not use the ordered list of audio files as listed above - but instead us the default audio playlist that can be created within a wordpress post, which produces the following code:

```
<div class="wp-playlist-tracks">
    <div class="wp-playlist-item wp-playlist-playing">
        <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/01_WhereToBegin-128.mp3">
            1. 
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-title">
                “Where To Begin”                </span>
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> — Alice Clayton</span>
        </a>
        <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">2:57</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-playlist-item">
        <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/02_BeingAlone-128.mp3">
            2. 
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-title">
                “Being Alone”               </span>
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> — Brosnan</span>
        </a>
        <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">3:15</div>
    </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I swap the javascript line from `document.getElementsByClassName('wpaudio');` to `document.getElementsByClassName('wp-playlist-caption');` in order to reference the different class name in the the new html, it doesn't display any names!

I am very new indeed to javascript so this may be obvious to someone skilled in that language, but I do have a limited knowlege of php.

Would anybody be able to explain why when i change the class name/reference in the above scenario I get no names displayed?

FYI I have also tried changing `document.getElementsByClassName()` to `document.querySelectorAll()` which also works well, when referencing the original class ('.wpaudio') - but again produces no result when referencing ('.wp-playlist-caption') or any other class name nested within it (such as .wp-playlist-item-title or .wp-playlist-item-artist).

Any help with the above would be most appreciated

Comment: If you run 'document.querySelectorAll('.wp-playlist-caption');' in console in your browser after there are items in playlist what it'll return?

Comment: Before, you were reading the `innerHTML` of the `p` elements with the class `wpaudio` - those contained the track name _only_. Now you are trying to work with the innerHTML of your `.wp-playlist-caption` elements - which contains much more than that, you have the item number in there, you have additional _HTML elements_ in there … Try selecting the `.wp-playlist-item-title` elements instead - those now contain your actual track names. (And if you don’t want the additional whitespace and curly quotes, then you’ll also have to trim them from the value.)

Comment: Hi @RauboLuk - not sure how to "run" something in console on a browser? Here's the actual live page (see link below). are you able to see what you're asking about via that? (https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/three-minute-heroes-vol-2-various-artists-album/)

Comment: Hi @CBroe - tried swapping to `.wp-playlist-item-title` but still no luck. It's on the live page at the moment viewable here. I understood what you were saying but still confused as to why it's not working: https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/three-minute-heroes-vol-2-various-artists-album/

Comment: _“not sure how to "run" something in console on a browser?”_ - and your Google is broken, too? https://techdows.com/2014/09/how-to-run-javascript-commands-in-chrome-and-firefox-browsers.html

Comment: sorry about that & thanks

Comment: OK, if I run `document.querySelectorAll('.wp-playlist-item-caption');` in Console I get this (not sure how to copy the complete result - does this shine a light on anything?):
`NodeList []
length: 0
__proto__: NodeList
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
item: ƒ item()
keys: ƒ keys()
length: (...)
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ NodeList()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "NodeList"
get length: ƒ length()
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Sorry getting in a mess here. Can't find a way to copy the complete result I get from running `document.querySelectorAll('.wp-playlist-caption');` what am I looking for in the result? Apologies but I'm new to a lot of these processes including how to share code on this forum.

Comment: I don't need whole log. Your query selectors doesn't find anything because when they are running there is nothing that match. That page is rendering this items after query selectors and they are not tracking future matches.

Comment: Ahhh . . .  I placed your suggestion `[...document.querySelectorAll('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-caption')].forEach(track => console.log(track.innerText))` into the console and everything came up beautifully!  All named correctly line after line. How do I get that to happen in my javascript?

Comment: OK now this is where I get lost! When you say replace `console.log()` with the content of the `for` do you mean the line `for (i=0; i<track_names.length; i++)`? Also I don't know what you mean by the "declaration of `track_name` to `track.innerText` - apologies for my lack of knowledge with this but if you could help me that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `wp-playlist-caption` has multiple nested elements, you can either query for each one of them and string them together or take the lazy route and use [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). That will extract the rendered plaintext inside the element and its children.

```
// Wait until the page has loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var field_to_update = document.getElementById('reactionForm_strongestTrack');
  field_to_update.innerHTML = '';
  var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
  elOptNew.text = '---'
  elOptNew.value = '';
  field_to_update.add(elOptNew);
  field_to_update.options[0].selected = true;

  // Search for all playlist-captions inside the playlist-tracks list.
  // 'Currently playing' has a playlist-caption too, 
  // limiting to the tracklist excludes it
  document.querySelectorAll('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-caption')
    .forEach( // The following arrow function will be called for each element
      track => {
        // There are nested elements but we just want the plaintext    
        let track_name = track.innerText;
        // Create a new element and append to the select as before
        let elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
        elOptNew.text = track_name.replace("&amp;", "&");
        elOptNew.value = track_name;

        field_to_update.add(elOptNew);
      });
});
```

Additional reference for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Hi @msg Thx so much for your answer. However, still no luck. There was a line above my original javascript code that maybe I should included in the first place? It is as follows: `var field_to_update = document.getElementById('reactionForm_strongestTrack');` followed by `field_to_update.innerHTML = '';`. I've tried changing `innerHTML` to `innerText` to match your code but still no luck with that one. Any ideas as to why your suggested answer is still not working?

Comment: Still no luck! what can it be?

Comment: @PhilLegg The playlist markup is modified by the `mediaelement.js` script that executes after yours, when yours executes, the playlist is in fact still an ordered list.

Comment: Hi @msg thx again - but how can I control the order in which the various js scripts run? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @PhilLegg [Yes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238777/how-to-change-script-order). And I think the script that actually modifies the playlist is `wp-playlist.js`. Add them both to the dependencies to be safe.

Comment: OK going to look into the link you sent and how to control the order the scripts run. Thx again for your help

Comment: Hi @msg OK while sorting out the order in which the scripts ran, I deactivated the caching plugin (W3 Total Cache) & then it worked! I then removed the `wp_enqueue_script` lines I was using to define the order in which the scripts ran and it still worked! So seems if you edit any javascript coding, you need to deactivate any caching software and then reactivate again, so it can (presumable) re evaluate any minifying or similar processes its doing. Have you experienced that sort of thing before?

Comment: @PhilLegg Yes, that sounds reasonable. It'll ultimately depend on your cache configuration. W3TC should offer a menu in the adminbar to 'Purge all caches' without having to deactivate the plugin itself.

Comment: cheers for the clarification re the 'Purge all caches' option in the admin bar - yes it's there. Anyway the page is working wonderfully now and thx for all your (& everyone else's) help in resolving this - & as usual I Iearnt lots along the way

Comment: Hi @msg you helped me get this javascript working back in Sept 20 but the script has now stopped working! Only changes on the website have been the usual ongoing wordpress & plugin updates (I've not actually changed any coding)> Any idea what could have caused this? I can't see any errors relating to this script showing up in dev tools / console - any ideas?

Comment: @PhilLegg The script itself still works, so the structure hasn't changed. Maybe the updates have messed with the loading order or it just takes more time to execute. You could try shuffling those again, introduce some delay or loop until the elements are present on the page.

Comment: Hi @msg - thx for getting back. Yes, was thinking script load order as well. Tried the method you suggested in previous post by including other scripts in the dependencies part: `($dep)` of `wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer )`. But when I included the 2 scripts you suggeted like so: `,array('wp-playlist.js','mediaelement.js'),` this script didn't even load! Have I written that correctly or is there another way to define the order that scripts load? Btw, what's the difference between a script's 'file name' & 'handle'? Maybe that's why the array didn't work?

Comment: @PhilLegg A handle is just an arbitrary name to identify a given script. It's usually the same as the name without the extension, but it doesn't have to. Take for instance two `script.js` files in two different plugins, you'll need a way to identify them so you'll use two different handles (the plugin name, for example). You can find more info in the [`wp_register_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) reference, including default scripts registered by wordpress (look for the `mediaelement` specially). You'd have to dig a bit for the playlist handle.

Comment: After trying options re script load order & registering scripts, I had no luck but after installing "Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" plugin & switching back to "legacy 1.12.4-wp" setting the script worked & loaded the list of tracks - so presumably issue relates to Wordpress dropping the "jQuery Migrate" on updates after 5.5. Have googled around to work out what I'd need to do to this script to make it work going forward but can't find much + can't see any errors on the Chrome Developers Cosole to see what's failing? Any ideas how to resolve as using this plugin is only a temporary fix?

Comment: No, not really, as this code doesn't use jQuery at all, it is vanilla javascript. The `wp-playlist` and `mediaelement` scripts changed the markup of the playlist elements, so maybe it's one of those plugins what's using jQuery indirectly and failing. I'd try updating them or going to the support forums, but you'd need something to go on first.

Comment: hmmm . . . interesting! So it doesn't use jQuery at all! Will have a further rethink (& take your point re wp-playlist & mediaelement possibly using jQuery). This is certainly trying my patience - but very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @msg or anyone - Still battling away at this! Tried various dependencies using `wp-mediaelement` & `wp-playlist` in array() to adjust script load order as well as using `async` & `defer` attributes to delay loading this `reactionform_js.js` script but no joy! Still works fine when website is switched back to JQuery legacy 1.12.4-wp (using plugin JQuery Migrate) but not when using current Wordpress default JQuery. Any other ideas RE load order / delaying script - or any other ideas I can ivestigate? Any help would be amazing as I really need to resolve this

Comment: Hey @PhilLegg, as I said, our code isn't using jQuery, so that should not be affected, but pinpointing the culprit is pretty hard since it depends on your actual installation, much more so without seeing the faulty behaviour in action. However, looks like the migration helper now [logs](https://make.wordpress.org/support/2020/12/handling-potential-jquery-issues-in-wordpress-5-6/) potential problems in 5.6. You'd have to update to that, though. Once identified you can open a support request for the outdated plugin. Or try to fix it yourself and come back to ask another question. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @msg Logged deprecations earlier [see log](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XvSAKABHxzzEDP8QDNokHpK_OabN43ymGDU7pfk1gto/edit?usp=sharing) Entries relating to page using this code in red but that's back in Feb! Sorry for not enabling current jQuery to show errors. Have done now [see live page](https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/jack-conman-seventh-sense-libido-album/) See also [image](https://share.getcloudapp.com/mXuKmJBk) showing field working with legacy 1.12.4-wp but not with Default frm Wordpress to show what I'm trying to achieve. Also on Dev Tools/Console it shows no error!

Comment: @PhilLegg Code still works as-is when executed in the console, so no problems related to markup changes, but there's some caching plugin enabled. I'd disable it (and minification too, as sometimes can screw things up) until you dial it in. Other than going through the tedious work, I'm out of ideas, I really do think this **must** come down to load order.